# How do I find what is missing from second string based on first string?

Tags: regex, perl

$a = "
fddf\n
dfdf\n
eeee\n"

$b = "
fddf\n
dfdf\n
pppp\n
erww\n"

The output should be "eeee\n" because it is missing in second string. I thought of using perl regular expression but it does not tell me the what is missing from the second string.

Comment: Please format your question. That's hard to understand right now.

Comment: @revo I updated the format of question.

Comment: I would use the [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff) module from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

First: always use strict and warnings, and don't use `$a` and `$b` outside of sort, they're [special](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Freenode::DollarAB).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x = " fddf\n dfdf\n eeee\n";
my $y = " fddf\n dfdf\n pppp\n erww\n";
my @x_chars = split //, $x;
my @y_chars = split //, $y;
my @missing_chars;
while (@x_chars and @y_chars) {
  my $next = shift @x_chars;
  if ($next eq $y_chars[0]) {
    shift @y_chars;
  } else {
    push @missing_chars, $next;
  }
}
push @missing_chars, @x_chars;
my $missing = join '', @missing_chars;
```

As mentioned CPAN modules like [String::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Diff) (wrapper of Algorithm::Diff) will provide a simpler and more comprehensive solution if your requirements become more complex.